# How to retrieve data length from form in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ant to know how can i get the length of array getting from form in AngularJs.

I have this form for example:

```
<form ng-submit="sendForm()">
   <table>
<tr ng-repeat="menu in menus">
    <td> {{ menu.label}}</td>
    <td>    
        <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="watch[]" ng-model="formModel.watchs[ menu.menu_id ]">
          <div class="slider blue round"></div>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="create[]" ng-model="formModel.create[ menu.menu_id ]">
          <div class="slider blue round"></div>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="edit[]" ng-model="formModel.edit[ menu.menu_id ]">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" ng-model="formModel.del[ menu.menu_id ]">
          <div class="slider red round"></div>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</tr>
```

And i get the data here:

```
$scope.sendForm= function(){

   var formData= $scope.formModel;
   console.log($scope.formModel.length); 
   for(var i=0; i<formData.length; i++){

   var sparseKeys = Object.keys(formData);
   console.log(sparseKeys);
 }
}
```

How can i get the length of the data?

Comment: shound it be $scope.formData.length?

Comment: no it's not working. 'formData' it's javascript variable he don't get $scope.

Comment: if its a javascript variable why you are using it in the view ? ng-model="formData ?

Comment: my mistake. i've change it. but that is not the problom

Comment: could you please clarify what is the error and your expected output again?
because, as long as I read, it seems like you want to get the length of `$scope.formModel` by `$scope.formModel.length` which is already existed in your code or do you want to get (for example) `$scope.formModel.watchs.length` etc. so people can help your with clear understanding :)

Comment: i am getting the data successfully. but i want to run on the data, because i need to take the key and the value of the data. i try to run on  loop for but the length is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the code it looks like formModel is an object not an array,
you can use:

```
for (var key in $scope.formModel) {
    if ($scope.formModel.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var myVal = $scope.formModel[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: it was undefined. but i solve it. i use a object loop like for (key in $scope.formModel) { ... }

Comment: but i don't use forEach bacause the cause the error of undefined